# How to set `this` in extended interface method to type variable

Tags: typescript

I'm making a library and users should be able to create a custom object that extends a TypeScript interface. This custom object is then passed to a library function that merges the custom object in an object with defaults and returns the result.

The custom object that extends the TypeScript interface can override methods from the interface. I want to set `this` in the method to the custom object. Currently I have this (failing) code:

```js
interface Thing<T extends SpecialThing = SpecialThing> {
    a: number
    derp(this: T, blah?: Partial<T>): T
}

interface SpecialThing extends Thing {
    b: string
}

function createThing<T extends Thing<T>>(options: T) {
    return Object.assign({
        a: 1,
        derp() {}
    }, options)
}

// userland:

interface CustomThing extends SpecialThing {
    c: boolean
}

createThing<CustomThing>({
    a: 1,
    b:'b',
    c: true,
    derp() {
        this.c // `this` should be CustomThing
        return this
    }
})
```

See the TypeScript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMA8rkQAekIAJgM7IDKADhAsHADYbbIC81dDzrIWAPmQBvAFDIJyOAC5kIAK4BbAEbRxk0tBoAKMJnKzUAGmTKmcdAH5ZABThQwjJngEBKQ6IC+o0aEixEFFp6Jz4sAmIIMkowkXUJZVlyMChsLx8YeRAERwB7EGQEKAg4SDC8CJIKNEx+FwFtXJo8kAM0VzjJZGKweSgCgHllACt6MAA6OHJyYCwQbTEurplkAEYjeKXNKB0O4W8uzxMmlvJXdNEAekvkeXJoczJpHz9oeCRkAGE7sFzFWKIVUowR4LFq4UWkgQsmUuVyTBKIAuRRKZXBOG+yT+YQakIkK3Wm0SAHJlMSNl1ocgUvIIBSNFptHtNl09MByOMEMhrsgAAZs8i85DkdC5eRMUimFCY37-cEsyQ9PoFAWbbyeVxAA). `SpecialThing` is the interface users can extend, `Thing` is more used internally.

It would be ok to only have `SpecialThing`, but I need the type variable `T` to pass to `derp(this: T)` and it seems silly to have users extend `SpecialThing` like so:

```js
interface CustomThing extends SpecialThing<CustomThing> {
    c: boolean
}
```

Comment: Uh, hmm... I'd normally suggest using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) for such behavior, but in your particular case, why do you need anything like that at all?  What about [this code](https://tsplay.dev/YmpeaW) doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the type variable for the `derp` method. I've updated the example to show why (it needs it for another argument and a return value).

Comment: Okay, then does polymorphic `this` work well enough for you, as in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/DWKooW)?

Comment: Yes!  Once I added `this: this` to `derp`'s signature it worked. Didn't know about _polymorphic this_, thanks a lot. Also for the superfast replies  You want to post an answer or shall I answer it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where an object type needs to make reference to itself that automatically propagates down to subtypes, you can often just write `this` for the type.  This is called [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) and can take the place of the sort of F-bounded polymorphism you see in Java and other languages of the form `interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {...}`.  Since your `Thing` looks like that to me, I'd see what happens if you remove the `T` generic type parameter and replace all references to `T` with `this`:

```
interface Thing {
    a: number
    derp(blah?: Partial<this>): this
}

interface SpecialThing extends Thing {
    b: string
}

function createThing<T extends Thing>(options: T) {
    return Object.assign({
        a: 1,
        derp() { }
    }, options)
}

interface CustomThing extends SpecialThing {
    c: boolean
}

createThing<CustomThing>({
    a: 1,
    b: 'b',
    c: true,
    derp() {
        this.c
        return this
    }
})
```

This all works as expected to me.  Note that didn't include the `this: this` parameter in `derp()` because you might not need it... Generally speaking the type of `this` inside a method implementation defaults to the polymorphic `this` type anyway, so there's not an obvious advantage to explicitly spelling it out.  It doesn't hurt though, and there might be some situations in which it *is* important but I'm not sure, and it would depend on the use case.

Anyway, that's my recommendation, given the example code.  I see that it's possible that there might be a disconnect between `Thing` and `SpecialThing`, (your original code had `T extends SpecialThing` and not `T extends Thing<T>`), so you could run into something weird with the `b` property.  You can probably address it if you need to with `this & SpecialThing` instead of `this` alone, but again, that depends on the use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyRycAXMiAK4C2ARtIcQCbQAOAFLQDZzoD85AApwoYYHC4AeMJgDOAPgCU5GcFn4AvvnyhIsRCgDKrCAnFcM2ZBAAekEE1lpMIHAWLJa5WWCjZN2jCUIAhiAPYgyAhQEHCQlq6SqNZ2EA5OCVjy7GGs4SCy5KiKeIxEMWCUUJEA8rQAVqZgAHRwsrLAWCDs7h7EZMgAjAA0ZX0sUBwluMhaHhrDyLn5sooB+AD0G8iUstA8DqTautDwSMgAwrtgYdSZKfaOyMam5ve9RAjktGFhXLEgdbRWLxFxYSRXHy3TLZD4kcgjMZeZAAcloKNGHi+yF8lAgmOYbHY0zGHlUsmaCFJxAqVUi5LGWg0iiAA)

Comment: In the actual code I needed to add `this: this` (else `this` becomes `any` in userland). Not sure why, but my example is a lot simpler than the actual code. Also, it should be `T extends SpecialThing` as in my first example. Thanks a lot for the extensive answer.